# How do i use the knife tool in blender 2.78c?

Tags: modeling

I am doing a tutorial on modeling and I try to use the knife tool(k + z) after choosing the object.  However it reports an error, can't rip selected surfaces.  Why?

Comment: maybe if you could show or describe those surfaces... ?

Comment: Are you actually pressing button on keyboard to activate knife? Error telling "can't rip selected faces" is related to Rip tool which is activated with V.

Comment: You should only need to press 'k' when in edit mode to activate the knife tool.

Comment: masterj2001: Z activates "cut through" when cutting